# Following-up "given a two dimensional linked list, create a flattened sorted list"

Tags: java, linked-list

> A node has a next and down pointer.  Merge the linked-list such that
>   end result is sorted. Here we have a top level linked-list, followed
>   by a down-list.
>
> If { 10 : {20, 30} , 35 { 40, 50 } } is the input data structure, it
>   means that 10 is connected to 35, using the next pointer. 10 is
>   connected to 20 and 20 to 30 using the down pointer, and 35 is
>   connected to 40 and 40 to 50 using the down pointer.
>
> Only the top level list {10 -> 35} use the next pointer, the down
>   level links {10 -> 20 -> 30} and {35 -> 40 -> 50} use the down pointer
>   ONLY.
>
> The output should be a list 10 - 20 - 30 - 35 - 40 - 50, and down ptr
>   should be null for all.

This question, like many of my previous questions, is attributed to [GeeksForGeeks](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/flattening-a-linked-list/).
This code was previously solved [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/56287/given-a-two-dimensional-linked-list-create-a-flattened-sorted-list).

Looking for code-review, best practices and optimizations.
Verifying complexity to be \$O(mn * logn)\$, where \$n\$ is the length of number of nodes linked by next ptr, while \$m\$ is the max length of the linked list through the down ptr.

```
public class FlattenLinkedList {

    private Node first;
    private Node last;
    private final PriorityQueue<Node> queue;
    private int size;

    public FlattenLinkedList(List<Integer> nodes) {
        queue = new PriorityQueue<Node>(11, new FlattenListComparator());
        for (Integer item : nodes) {
            add(item);
        }
    }

    /**
     * 
     *  10  -(next)->  20 -(next)-> 30
     *   |             |            |
     *  down          down         down
     *   |             |            |
     *   12            25          35
     *   |             |            |
     *   100          400          200
     *   
     * To represent such a list in the map,
     * keys of such a map would be 10, 20 and 30.
     * The values of such a map would be
     * key: 10, values: a list of 12, 100
     * key: 20, values: a list of 25, 400
     * key: 30, values: a list of 35, 200
     * 
     */
    public FlattenLinkedList(LinkedHashMap<Integer, List<Integer>> nodes) {
        queue = new PriorityQueue<>(11, new FlattenListComparator());
        for (Integer item : nodes.keySet()) {
            add(item);
        }

        Node head = first;
        for (List<Integer> items : nodes.values()) {
            addDown(head, items);
            head = head.next; 
        }
    }


    private void add(int item) {
        final Node node = new Node(item);
        queue.add(node);
        if (first == null) {
            first = last = node;
        } else {
            last.next = node;
            last = node;
        }
        size++;
    }

    private void addDown(Node head, List<Integer> list) {
        Node prev = null;
        for (Integer item : list) {
            Node node = new Node(item);
            if (prev == null) {
                prev = node; 
                head.down = node;
            } else {
                prev.down = node;
            }
            prev = node;
        }
        size = size + list.size();
    }


    private static class FlattenListComparator implements Comparator<Node> {
        @Override
        public int compare(Node node1, Node node2) {
            return node1.item - node2.item;
        }
    }

    private static class Node {
        private Node next;
        private Node down;
        private int item;

        Node(int item) {
            this.item = item;
        }
    }

    public void flatten() {
        Node prev = null;
        while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
            Node currNode = queue.poll();
            if (prev == null) {
                prev = first = currNode;
            } else {
                prev.next = currNode;
                prev = currNode;
            }
            if (currNode.down != null) {
                queue.add(currNode.down);
            }
        }
    }


    public int[] toArray() {
        int[] arr = new int[size];
        int count = 0;
        for (Node x = first; x != null; x = x.next) {
            arr[count++] = x.item;
        }
        return arr;
    }
}

public class FlattenLinkedListTest {

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        LinkedHashMap<Integer, List<Integer>> map = new LinkedHashMap<Integer,  List<Integer>>();
        map.put(10,  Arrays.asList(20,   30));
        map.put(40,  new ArrayList<Integer>());
        map.put(70,  Arrays.asList(80,   90));
        map.put(100, Arrays.asList(110, 120));

        FlattenLinkedList flat = new FlattenLinkedList(map);
        flat.flatten();
        int[] arr = {10, 20, 30, 40, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120};
        assertArrayEquals(arr, flat.toArray());
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() {
        LinkedHashMap<Integer, List<Integer>> map1 = new LinkedHashMap<Integer,  List<Integer>>();
        map1.put(1,  Arrays.asList(80, 90));
        map1.put(2,  Arrays.asList(70, 75));
        map1.put(3,  Arrays.asList(60, 65));
        map1.put(4,  Arrays.asList(50, 55));
        map1.put(5,  Arrays.asList(40, 45));

        FlattenLinkedList flat1 = new FlattenLinkedList(map1);
        flat1.flatten();
        int[] arr1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 75, 80, 90};
        assertArrayEquals(arr1, flat1.toArray());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
private void addDown(Node head, List<Integer> list) {
    Node prev = null;
    for (Integer item : list) {
        Node node = new Node(item);
        if (prev == null) {
            prev = node; 
            head.down = node;
        } else {
            prev.down = node;
        }
        prev = node;
    }
    size = size + list.size();
}
```

This set of statements seems weird to me:

```
        Node node = new Node(item);
        if (prev == null) {
            prev = node; 
            head.down = node;
        } else {
            prev.down = node;
        }
        prev = node;
```

if prev is null, you set it to node, do some things, then set it to node again. Seems like it's not needed.

```
size = size + list.size();
```

I'd use `+=` for that.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice: Declare your collection-type properties as the generic form (Queue) rather than the specific form (PriorityQueue) unless you specifically need a method only available in the implementation class.

As this is a completely internal property it's not that important, but it is a best practice.

another point: I would not use the double assigment (prev = first = node) but rather assign them separately. just like I would prefer testing

```
if (first == null)
  first = node;
// rather than
if (prev == null) {
  first == node;
```